# Pick up changes in json files that are being read by pyspark readstream?

Tags: pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, azure-synapse, delta-lake

I have json files where each file describes a particular entity, including it's state. I am trying to pull these into Delta by using readStream and writeStream. This is working perfectly for new files. These json files are frequently updated (i.e., states are changed, comments added, history items added, etc.). The changed json files are not pulled in with the readStream. I assume that is because readStream does not reprocess items. Is there a way around this?

One thing I am considering is changing my initial write of the json to add a timestamp to the file name so that it becomes a different record to the stream (I already have to do a de-duping in my writeStream anyway), but I am trying to not modify the code that is writing the json as it is already being used in production.

Ideally I would like to find something like the changeFeed functionality for Cosmos Db, but for reading json files.

Any suggestions?

Thankss!

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by the Spark Structured Streaming - after file is processed it won't be processed again.

The closest to your requirement is only exist in [Databricks' Autoloader](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/auto-loader.html) - it has option [cloudFiles.allowOverwrites option](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/auto-loader.html#does-auto-loader-process-the-file-again-when-the-file-gets-appended-or-overwritten) that allows to reprocess modified files.

P.S. Potentially if you use `cleanSource` option for file source (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources), then it may reprocess files, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks for the info Alex, it does help me for other purposes, but not for this. cleanSource will help me clear out files and keep it from having the overhead of having to track directory listing on a large dir, but the checkpoint prevents reprocessing even so. For Autoloader, it sounds great, but I didn't mention that I am working in Azure Synapse and Autoloader is a Databricks feature. I have other Databricks projects where I may look into it.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that you're using Synapse, but I don't know such functionality for non-Databricks implementations